# change lattice plot axis label

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I've got a pretty basic `xyplot` where I want to label the axis on the top (not bottom). Is there a possibility of doing so within the specific `xyplot` command - without changing trellis settings for other plots?

For the axis itself I found a way:

```
x=list(at=c(2,5,8),alternating=2, tck = c(0,1))
```

but not for

```
xlab = list(label="CH4 concentration [uM]")
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out via

```
scales=list(x=list(at=c(2,5,8), alternating=2, tck = c(0,1))
```